# Save associated in cakephp 3 not working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

My save associated in cakephp3 (3.1.5 and 3.0) is not working.

`users` table relation with`user_profiles` table is  hasOne and `user_profiles` table relation with `users` table is belongsTo.

When I want to save a user record with associated user_profile record, user record saves in `users` table but no record is saved in associated table `user_profiles`. I have no error in error.log

---

### Entities

for both of them =>

```
protected $_accessible = [
  * => true
];
```

---

### Users Controller

```
public function add()
{
    $data = [
        'email' => 'example@test.com',
        'username' => 'Example',
        'password' => '123456789',
            'user_profile' => [
                'first_name' => 'John',
                'last_name' => 'Smit',
                'phone' => '123456798'
            ] 
    ];
    $entity = $this->Users->newEntity();
    $entity = $this->Users->patchEntity($entity, $data);

    if ($this->Users->save($entity, [
        'associated' => ['UserProfiles']
    ])) {
        $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    } else {
        $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }

}
```

Comment: Instead of creating duplicates, edit your original question and fill it with proper information. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34369905/save-associated-in-cakephp-3-0-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Your `'associated' => ['UserProfiles']` is on wrong place. add him to `newEntity()` or `patchEntity()`;

```
...
$entity = $this->Users->patchEntity($entity, $data, [
        'associated' => ['UserProfiles']
    ]);

    if ($this->Users->save($entity))
...
```

Comment: First level associations are being merged by default, using associated is only necessary for deeper levels, or for disabling/restricting merging of associations.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Above reply is not working please help me out.